# TCPDF openssl error creating PKCS7 structure warning

Tags: php, pdf, openssl

Estoy intentando generar un PDF firmado utilizando [la librería TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
App::import('Vendor','mtcpdf');

$pdf = new MTCPDF('L');

$pdf->SetProtection(array('copy'), '', null, 0, null);

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->Image($imagen, -7, 1, 310, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);

if(!empty($imagentrasera)){
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->Image($imagentrasera, -7, 1, 310, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
}



if(!empty($certificado_digital)){

    $info = array(
    'Name' => __('Certificado PDF',true),
    'Location' => '',
    'Reason' => '',
    'ContactInfo' => '',
    );

    $certificado_crt = 'file://'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].Configure::read('directorioinstalacion').'app/webroot/Documentos/certificados/certificado.cer';
    $certificado_key = 'file://'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].Configure::read('directorioinstalacion').'app/webroot/Documentos/certificados/key.key';
    $pdf->setSignature($certificado_crt,$certificado_key, '', '', 1, $info);
}


echo $pdf->Output(__('Certificado',true).'.pdf', 'D');
```

He generado el "certificado.cer" utilizando el siguiente comando y basándome en un p12 de la casa de la moneda y timbre:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out certificado.cer -nodes
```

Y el fichero "key.key" lo genero tomando la zona de clave privada del fichero p12 y guardandolo como .key.

Se produce el siguiente error en esta línea:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign($tempdoc, $tempsign, $this->signature_data['signcert'], array($this->signature_data['privkey'], $this->signature_data['password']), array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);


Warning (2): openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error creating PKCS7 structure! [CORE\vendors\tcpdf\tcpdf.php, line 7594]
```

Utilizo PHP 5.6.2 y las rutas a los certificados son correctas porque hago un echo get_file_contents y lo muestra correctamente.

He estado buscando por todos lados y nada, agradecería algo de ayuda.

Un saludo!!